# java edit object with too many attributes

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

#### background

I have a class `Person` which has a lot of attributes.

#### what I want

to allow the user to edit those attributes.

#### what I have tried 1

create function its parameters is all the attributes, create a sql statement , then call the stored procedure.

#### The problem

maybe the user wants to edit just one of his parameters (and this is the more common situation), so in my way , he has to input all the attributes even if he wants to edit just one of them.

#### what I have tried 2

create function for each attribute to edit it.

#### The problem

I have to code toooooooooooo many functions with toooooo many sql statements.

#### My question

what is the best approach for solving the problem ? is there any design pattern for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Best approach will be your approach .

Comment: which one of them do you mean? 1st or 2nd?

Comment: Why don't you just update all the attributes of person in your sql-update? You have only one single sql statement and attributes the user did not edit just remain the same.

Comment: @nansen that is really a very simple approach But, the user has a lot of attributes so if he wants to edit just one charector of his name (1 byte) that means I will go and update all his info which may be (1MB)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: this is a question of (maybe premature) optimization. And before I am not absolutely sure that the 'simple' approach is really too expensive (or inflexible in the long run), I would always prefer it over the complex one.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can take the attributes to update as a `Map<String,Object`> where **key**==your attribute name and **value**=Value of the attribute.

In this way

- You can take multiple attributes by the means of `Map`
- You can even take single attribute to update without restricting the user to give value to other attributes

Once the user supplies the same, you can iterate through the entries of the map and update the `Person` object accordingly.

EDIT: Say `Person` has `name` and `age` properties, then you supply the method `updatePerson` a `Map` containing entries where `[key is"name" and value as "Actual Name"], [key is"age" and value as "15"]` etc

Then in your update method, you can iterate over the `Map` and get the attributes to update like below

```
public boolean updatePerson(Map<String,Object> valueMap) {
    for(Entry<String, Object> enrty : valueMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = enrty.getKey();
        //Person p = ... logic to get person
        if("name".equals(key)) {
            //p.setName(enrty.getValue());
        }
        else
        if("age".equals(key)) {
            //...
        }
        //finally update Person into DB...  
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not familiar with this map thing, would you please put a very small code as an example ?

Comment: thanks for your update, I will try it and think about it, just after 1 hour to catch my home

Comment: my suggestion is to use builder pattern it is designed exact purpose which you want.